# ReferenceError: queue is not defined, how to define it?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to implement the functionality of a music bot into my discord bot, but upon saving my work in atom, node reports that the phrase "queue" is not defined.

`const serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);`

> ReferenceError: queue is not defined

Obviously the problem stems from the fact that the phrase "queue" was not defined earlier in the file and therefore it doesn't understand how to use it, only problem is, I don't know how to add it.

I've tried searching for this specific issue already but the fixes that were provided either didn't work or did not apply to my situation (one variation is for the phrase "bot" that was no longer a class, but discord.js doesn't seem to have anything for queue; not to mention it was related to the setup section of the bot anyway.)

```
client.on('message', async message => {
   if (message.author.bot) return;
   if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
});
const serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);
                   *^ problem*
if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}play`)) {
  execute (message, serverQueue);
  return;
} else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}skip`)) {
  skip(message, serverQueue);
  return;
} else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}stop`)) {
  stop(message, serverQueue);
  return;
} else {
  message.channel.send('That is not a vallid command :(')
}
```

Problem occurs on line `const serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id)` on `queue.get`

It's expected to start up and allow me to connect it to a voice channel for audio playback from sites like YouTube for music listening, but instead, it crashes on startup and all I get is the error that the phrase "queue" is not defined.

Comment: You're closing the `message` handler before reaching that part of the code. Is this intentional?

Comment: Yes, leaving it open causes node to have an unexpected end of input error on the last line.

Comment: your if statement is running outside of your message handler... also, i think you should call it with client.queue

Comment: @Mayravixx I'm referring to an entirely separate problem from the one you posted about. You're referencing `message.guild.id` after `message` goes out of scope. Try moving `});` from line 4 to line 19.

Comment: Moving `});` to line 19 (actually 38 in my case) causes the error `unexpected token )` and using client.queue does work, but then the `message` in `message.guild.id` becomes undefined.

***Edit:*** counted wrong, line 39 is the line 19, not 38; after adding `});` to line 39, the bot starts up fine and it works with my test command just fine.

Comment: @Mayravixx your main issue is that you are missing a closing bracket or parenthesis at the end of your Code. What you have done to Remedy that is move code around improperly. Place the code where IronFlare is stating, and then find the proper way to close your code. Alternatively you can post your entire code on a Pastebin and link it for us. Im almost positive thats your issue. Improper closing of your initial attempt at coding this function.

Comment: Yes, it was my issue. I was putting it on line 38 instead of line 39 since I made the mistake of counting wrong. After putting `});` on line 39, the bot works again.

Answer (score 0):

For thoroughness, I'm porting my answer in the comments to a proper answer, now that the author has confirmed that it solved their issue.

As I wrote in the comments, the errors in the author's code were due to incorrect scoping. More specifically, the `message` handler, which started on line 1 of the code sample, was inadvertently closed by the `});` on line 4.

This caused `message.guild.id` to throw an undefined error because the `message` variable was scoped to the callback function, and thus didn't exist outside of the first four lines. Although we don't see the initial definition of the `queue` variable, the author indicated that correcting the placement of their brackets fixed the issue.

```
client.on('message', async message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  const serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);

  if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}play`)) {
    execute (message, serverQueue);
    return;
  } else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}skip`)) {
    skip(message, serverQueue);
    return;
  } else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}stop`)) {
    stop(message, serverQueue);
    return;
  } else {
    message.channel.send('That is not a valid command :(')
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line in your code.

```
const queue = new Map()
```